# Deactivate tabs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, tabs

Is there a way to disable Notepad++ tabs?

I would like to open each file in a new window. Not necessarily in a new instance but there should be a new tab in the windows task bar as well. Essentially I want Notepad++ mimic MS Notepads behaviour in regards to open multiple files. I'm using Notepad++ in it's portable version, so I would prefer but not limit a possible answer to a solution that works with it.

UPDATE: currently (as of Okt2020) it is not possible to setup multi instances without sacrifice features like autosave which (unfortunately) I require to work properly

Comment: Settings > General > Tab Bar > Hide is the closest.

Comment: @DavidPostill already tried it, only hides the tab bar, doesn't change notepads behaviour at all.

Comment: You need to play with Settings > Preferences > Multi Instance as well but close all your tabs first.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did as well, still doesn't give me the desired behaviour, quite a few use cases where it still opens in tabs.

Comment: Did you restart after making the changes?

Comment: @DavidPostill I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimick this by opening each file **from outside of Notepad++** using a command with `multiInst` [command-line parameter][1]:

```
notepad++.exe C:\myfile.txt -multiInst
```

and later

```
notepad++.exe C:\anotherfile.txt -multiInst
```

etc...

You can put this into a batch file and then use it to open anything in Notepad++.

I am not saying you should attempt to open a file from the inside of Notepad++ (menu File > Open) if you say that based on what you tried this way is unreliable.

---

Update after question update:

Use more sophisticated batch file which will clone Notepad++ program directory including all six configuration XML files into a new temp directory.* This way you will have open each file in separate Notepad++. Create a scheduled task which will delete all such temp directories/hardlinks if no Notepad++ is running at the moment (what is a simplified but reliable approach).

*) Use portable version of N++ for this configured for MultiInst. You can use hard links `mklink /j` with dirs and `mklink /h` with files to save you from actually copying most of N++ files. This will make the cloning super-fast.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately my goal was to open the file directly (without creating a batch file). Your solution could be implementet without a batch file as well but it's possible now to do it through the setup without a batch file. But you have to sacrifice features like autosave (see question update).

Comment: @Albin – please consider this: "my goal was to open the file directly" was not stated in the question, as well as the updated part. Moving target is not a good StackExchange practice. Anyway, I will add alternative solution for you now.

Comment: It's sort of "stated" by my statement "mimic MS Notepads behaviour", but in general I agree with you, sorry for not being specific enough. If you have a solution that works with the autosave, that would be great. I tried it but the autosave only works for the first instance.

Comment: @Albin – see the latest update. This should be doable and not overly difficult. Before, test it manually if multi-instance created this way will allow AutoSave or not.

Comment: Interesting idea, I have to see if I can make it work without creating a batch file for each file I want to open...